# Has John Wick ever eaten throughout his adventure?

Tags: john-wick, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

Being someone who watched the three John Wick "Chapters", I am quite intrigued on how John managed to fight across the world without seemingly having the urge to eat.

Especially in Chapter 3 he travels  to various places.

Assuming he did not manage eat when changing his attire (the desert scene), he has not eaten for quite a long period of time.

Which begs the question does John  Wick ever eat in the movies?

Comment: Just because we don't see it doesn't mean he doesn't. Frankly, watching Wick eat airline food would not be the most riveting use of my cinema time.

Comment: Not sure of John Wick but [Keanu eat steak](https://www.mensjournal.com/health-fitness/keanu-reeves-lifetime-iconic-badassery-why-he-eats-steak-big-fight-scenes-and/).

Comment: [TVTropes' Law Of Conservation Of Detail](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheLawOfConservationOfDetail) has you covered

Comment: Same reason we don't see him go to the bathroom.

Comment: What exact time period are you considering to be "his adventure"? Are we including all of the events of all three movies (excluding flashbacks)? Only events that happened from the point the Russians broke into his house in the first movie?

Answer (score 3):

We don't see him sleep either (I don't remember if in the beginning of Chapter two he was sleeping or was just preparing to go to bed). But we assume he slept (and eaten) during those travels. Chapter two continuity beginning suggest that John stored the dog somewhere while he went to Russians to get the car back. So it was one day/night event ending in the morning when Mechanic arrive. Then he have visit to repay the debt. And later his house is being destroyed.
Because we know he didn't slept at Continental (his nap being interrupted by attempt to kill him) he had to be exhausted. 
And because flight to Rome from New York take 8 hours we can assume he slept during that travel and eaten something while waiting for the boarding. For this type of movies showing him eating and sleeping is used only to build suspense (hence the scene of Willem Defoe character "waking up" John by shooting the pillow).

We never see John Wick eat. And when we see him drinking he drinks alcohol.

Comment: We also see John Wick taking some kinds of medicine..